# Issue with Objective c passing object to javascript function call

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, stringbyevaluatingjavascr

Here is an example of what is happening: It appears that when an apostrophe is used in a word such as I'm it does not work in my string when sent to the javascript function call. I have read about adding backslash in front of the apostrophe like so I\'m but this still does not work. I noticed on js function call onScan('%@') the apostrophe cannot be replaced with "quotations" and when brackets are used to pass parameters that also does not help. Also changing NSMutableString to just NSString does not change this example or affect the answer of this request. Any help is appreciated.

```
    NSMutableString*messagText= @"I'm posting on stack.";

    messageText = [[messageText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'"
                                                        withString:@"\'"]
                                                        mutableCopy];

    NSString *javascriptString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"onScan('%@')", messageText];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptString];
```

Comment: show the code where you have added the backslash for the singlQuote.

Comment: this has been updated as you requested. Thanks!

Comment: can you explain why this works?

Comment: to escape a special character you need to use \\ instead of \ . if you use one \, it is considered as a part of string

Comment: sorry but why do you have to use 2 backslash instead of 1. What requires that? JavaScript? Objective-C? Html? I cant seem to find this explained anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To escape a single quote, you need double backslash
Try this:

```
NSString *messagText= @"I'm posting on stack.";
if ([messagText containsString:@"'"]) {
        messagText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"onScan('%@')",[messagText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"]];
}
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: messagText];
```

Comment: This worked!.... I upvoted this answer however I got the following reply from stack " Thanks for feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change publicly displayed post score.